# How can I know on what date and time the user has clicked on a button and then print it in another Django template?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have these two buttons found in my Django .html:

```
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="margin: 1em;">
        <a id="btn-aceptar" href="{% url 'cambiar_estado_factura' factura.id_factura 2 %}" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mx-2" style="width: 150px;">Aceptar</a>
        <a id="btn-rechazar" href="{% url 'cambiar_estado_factura' factura.id_factura 3 %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg mx-2" style="width: 150px;">Rechazar</a>
    </div>
```

I have those two buttons in the `d_facturaspendientes.html` and what I want to know is how can I get the date and time when the user clicks on one of the buttons.
That date and time, I want to print it in `facturasvalidadas.html`, but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone give me a hand?

Below I attach the table and the commented line where the date and time should go:

```
    <table class="table" style="padding: 1em;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Proveedor</th>
          <th>Fecha de emisión</th>
          <th>Fecha de validación</th>
          <th>Importe</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for factura in facturas %}
        <tr class="factura-row-link"
          onclick="window.location='{% url 'v_facturasvalidadas_details' factura.id_factura %}'">
          <td>{{ factura.id_factura }}</td>
          <td>{{ factura.id_proveedor.nombre }}</td>
          <td>{{ factura.fecha_factura_recibida }}</td>
          <td>HERE SHOULD BE THE DATE AND TIME THAT WE HAVE HEARD WHEN THE USER HAS CLICKED ON THE BUTTONS</td>
          <td>{{ factura.importe }} €</td>
          <td>{{ factura.id_estado.value }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to know the day and time when the user hits the button. Keep in mind, that each button is going to be pressed at a different time, so you don't have to save the time of the first validation date, so the time is different.

Comment: Obviously it should be checked in the backend if it requires a secure timestamp that can not be manipulated by the user. in any case, you should create an event that POST to the Backend and in the backend a function that stored the data in a table.

Comment: The problem with that is that if I make changes to the database, different users will be able to see the date and that is not the goal. What I want is OK, I have the date when I modified the invoice, then I print it in valid invoices. Now, I sign another invoice, as it has another date and another time, then I see it in valid invoices, without modifying the previous invoice.

Comment: you can add a new table for that... A user will not see the content of a database unless he have direct access to it.